# Getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() for no reason

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP Version 5.5.14, and in **phpinfo()**, I can see curl being enabled and installed. !

[Screen shot of my phpinfo() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO2BL.png)

Even from **get_defined_functions()** function, I can see **curl_init()** exists.

I checked my php.ini file, and there also extension for curl is activated.

[image: hp ini screen shot]

Still, I am getting **Call to undefined function curl_init()**

Please help.

Code :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:4001/savecard");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//grab URL and pass it to the browser
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output);
?>
```

output :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in test.php on line 2
```

Comment: And where is your PHP code?

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Can you share that code with us and the *actual* error message with us?

Comment: Added the code and the output.

Comment: Though http://localhost:4001/savecard works fine on my browser and returns expected output.

Comment: So this was posted over two years ago...did you figure it out?